# Get previous Span in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to get the previous span in my html that was used as label, I've tried jquery .prev([selector]), but the selector doesn't work, it return the parent span of the input field I'm getting.

here is my HTML and script:

```
<form>
<span class="a-text-bold">
    Add product detail
</span>

<div class="a-section a-spacing-base">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
        <span class="a-text-bold">
        Brand name
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="form-item-action">
        <span class="a-declarative">
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" value="Bubble Goth Babes" id="data-draft-brand-name" autocomplete="off" name="data[draft][brand_name]" class="a-input-text a-form-normal  gear-filter-control-characters-textbox  lock-needs-hidden">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-base">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
        <span class="a-text-bold">
        Title of product
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="form-item-action">
        <span class="a-declarative">
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" value="Cute Zombkitty Zombie Kitten Neon Funny Brain Cat" id="data-draft-name-en-us" autocomplete="off" name="data[draft][brand_name]" class="a-input-text a-form-normal  gear-filter-control-characters-textbox  lock-needs-hidden">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
    <button onclick="getLabelAndValue()">Get</button>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function getLabelAndValue(){

        var focused = document.activeElement;

        var form = document.getElementsByName(focused.form.name);

        for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            if(form[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" && form[i].getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() == "text"){
                console.log($("#" + form[i].id).prev("span .a-text-bold").text()); //Doesn't work
                console.log(form[i].value); //Already working, means I'm pointing to right element
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

What I'm trying to see on the console.log are:

```
//Brand Name
//Bubble Goth Babes

//Title of Product
//Cute Zombkitty Zombie Kitten Neon Funny Brain Cat
```

**note**: I'm already able to get the form elements value (`form[i].value`), just the span before it with className `a-text-bold` is what I need to get.

Comment: `var focused = document.activeElement;` is the button, `focused.form.name` is the name of the form, which is empty string so `var form = document.getElementsByName(focused.form.name);` should be empty collection. You are iterating a collection of zero elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with using jQuery for everything, since it's so easy to use. Here's essentially the same code, only getting the label a different way. Note that you can't use `prev()`, since the `span` is not a sibling of the `input`. You have to travel up the DOM to a common ancestor, then back down the the `span`.

```js
function getLabelAndValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = e.target.form;
  var inputs = $('input[type="text"]', form);

  inputs.each(function (input) {
    // get the closest common ancestor, then find the "a-text-bold" span.
    var label = $(this).closest(".a-section").find(".a-text-bold").text().trim();
    console.log(label);
    console.log(this.value); //Already working, means I'm pointing to right element
  });

}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("get").addEventListener("click", getLabelAndValue);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <span class="a-text-bold">
    Add product detail
</span>

  <div class="a-section a-spacing-base">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
      <span class="a-text-bold">
        Brand name
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="form-item-action">
        <span class="a-declarative">
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" value="Bubble Goth Babes" id="data-draft-brand-name" autocomplete="off" name="data[draft][brand_name]" class="a-input-text a-form-normal  gear-filter-control-characters-textbox  lock-needs-hidden">
        </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-base">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-mini">
      <span class="a-text-bold">
        Title of product
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="form-item-action">
        <span class="a-declarative">
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" value="Cute Zombkitty Zombie Kitten Neon Funny Brain Cat" id="data-draft-name-en-us" autocomplete="off" name="data[draft][brand_name]" class="a-input-text a-form-normal  gear-filter-control-characters-textbox  lock-needs-hidden">
        </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button id="get">Get</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This also works, I also tried closest, but I guess I was missing the .find() function Thanks